# What does tensorflow.keras.utils.normalize actually do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/normalize) only says that it "Normalizes a Numpy array."

By normalization I expect that it makes the `mean = 0` and standard `deviation = 1`.

But when i run it on an array of [1,2,3], I get the following array:

```
[0.26726124 0.53452248 0.80178373]
```

Which has `mean = 0.53`, and `std = 0.21`.

It would be good to know what it means by `normalize`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it L2-normalizes the given array, i.e., it makes the sum of squares of each element of the array to be equal to one. You can find more information about L2-normalization by googling it.

Comment: Plus, many machine learning algorithms assume that the input array is L2-normalized.